# Subsequent CloudWatch Alarm notifications to SNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, amazon-cloudwatch

When I use CloudWatch alarm to trigger an AutoScaling action, it repeatedly trigger the ASG actions. In other words, a subsequent set of N Alarms with state ALARM will trigger N actions on ASG. This behavior was not observed for a SNS action, instead it's triggering only within the 1st event when the Alarm changes from OK to ALARM. Is it possible achieve the same action behavior on SNS similar to ASG?

Comment: Were you able to configure the SNS to receive subsequent notifications?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An Amazon CloudWatch alarm will only trigger an Amazon SNS notification when the alarm ***enters* the `ALARM` state**. That is, it triggers only once, and only when moving from something that isn't `ALARM` into the `ALARM` state.

The same CloudWatch alarm, however, will **continue to trigger** an Auto Scaling Policy.

For example, if an alarm is set to trigger when average CPU Utilization is above 80%, then the alarm will continue to trigger the Scaling Policy while the alarm is in the `ALARM` state. The Scaling Policy also has a **warmup period**, during which no additional scaling actions will take place (unless multiple steps are defined and another step limit has been breached).

The above behaviours are intentional and cannot be configured differently.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I've seen at your profile you work for Amazon, is there any plan to provide similar feature as Alarm->ASG on Alarm->SNS?

Comment: I have no knowledge of the product plans for these services. You are always welcome to submit feature requests via your Account Manager, or via the **Feedback** button in the AWS management console.

Comment: If anyone looking for official doc for above answer, like me, here it is - https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudwatch-alarms-trigger-actions/

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Do you know if a CloudWatch alarm in ALARM state also will continue to trigger an Application Auto Scaling Policy (and not just an EC2 Auto Scaling Policy)?